# Cleanest way to make big native image small on bootstrap col

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `row` with `3 col`, in each `col` I have one `image` which is original size is: `197px 197px`

I have the row aligned center with mx-auto, you can see [here](http://residenciarucab.es/rucab/contacto.html).

The problem is that I don't want the image to fill the 100% of the col container. I tried to add padding-left and right with the `pl-5` `pr-5` max that's bootstrap gives, but it's not enough, and I don't want to make new style, I want the clean way with bootstrap, is there any way to make the `image` resized like `32px 32px` with `bootstrap` and maintain the `horizontal alignment` on `center`?

```
  <section>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
 <div class="header-section bg-rosa">
        <div style="max-width: calc(34em + 5vw);">
          <h1>¿DÓNDE ESTAMOS?</h1>
          </div>
          </div>
        <div class="map-responsive">
        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3105.7869420542415!2d-7.016885748766864!3d38.88311615529015!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0xd16e38ab4d4e259%3A0x9a38319e3a49cfca!2sResidencia+Universitaria+Caja+Badajoz!5e0!3m2!1ses!2ses!4v1554163852202!5m2!1ses!2ses" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4"><img class="img-fluid" src="img/contacto/UBICACION-02.png"/></div>
  <div class="col-sm-4"><img class="img-fluid" src="img/contacto/TELEFONO-02.png"/></div>
  <div class="col-sm-4"><img class="img-fluid" src="img/contacto/RELOJ-02.png"/></div>
</div>
          </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

[image]

Comment: can't you use img-responsive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the point of not adding custom css because as far as I know you won't be able to accomplish it simply using bootstrap, you can just add a class to the `img` tags:

`<div class="col-sm-4"><img class="img-fluid p32" src="img/contacto/UBICACION-02.png"/></div>
  <div class="col-sm-4"><img class="img-fluid p32" src="img/contacto/TELEFONO-02.png"/></div>
  <div class="col-sm-4"><img class="img-fluidp32" src="img/contacto/RELOJ-02.png"/></div>`

and adding a simple css rule ( after the bootstrap import tag ) :

`p32{
  max-width: 32px;
}`

Comment: And how I can make each image separate like the screenshot that I just uploaded to the question? Thanks.

Comment: just add some padding for left and right to the same class and it should work,

Comment: Edit: if it doesn't work just increase the row's width until you get the satisfying results.